# Duplicates over 2 columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

So I am trying to get any pairs of tables that have an attribute with the same name and same data type in MYSQL.

```
SELECT distinct a.table_name,b.table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a  
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b on a.column_name=b.column_name   
and a.data_type=b.data_type  
WHERE a.table_schema='Online_food'  
and b.table_schema='Online_food'  
and a.table_name<>b.table_name
```

(Online_Food is my database)

The issue is I am getting two rows
(customer,order)
(order,customer)

But I want just one of them. Any one of them.
Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude half of the searches you could do:

```
SELECT distinct a.table_name, b.table_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a  
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b ON a.column_name = b.column_name   
AND a.data_type = b.data_type  
WHERE a.table_schema = 'Online_food'  
AND b.table_schema = 'Online_food'  
AND STRCMP(a.table_name,b.table_name) > 0
```

By selecting those results where one table name is, alphanumerically, bigger than the other table name, you make sure only `0.5*n*n-n` comparisons are done, where `n` is the number of tables.

Comment: Worked like I wanted it to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could impose an ordering on your results.  If you change the condition

```
a.table_name<>b.table_name
```

to

```
a.table_name < b.table_name
```

then only one of the results will be returned:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.table_name,b.table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a  
     JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b
     ON a.column_name = b.column_name  
         AND a.data_type = b.data_type
         AND a.table_schema = b.table_schema
WHERE a.table_schema = 'Online_food' 
    AND a.table_name < b.table_name
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks.